# Trying to update dates in database with dynamically created forms

Tags: php, mysql

So i've created an administration page that creates X-number of forms based on how many users we have in our database, each of which have a submit button next to them to submit changes to the dates we have in our DBs. My problem is that when I want to get the value of what gets posted I can't extract exactly what I need from what gets posted. It gets saved into an array called and when I print_r the array I get exactly what I want, which is:

```
  [1] => "whatever date they typed in" 
  (obviously the 1 changes depending on which item they changed the date of)
```

I need be able to query my datebase by:

```
  UPDATE users SET subdate="whatever they typed in" WHERE id="the array reference number"
```

I know exactly what I need to do, I'm just not as familiar with SQL as i'd like to be, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code for reference:

```
<div class="form-section grid12" id="changedates">
<h1>Change Dates</h1>
    <?php
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin='y'");
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h5><?php echo $row['displayname'];?></h5>
      </td>

      <td>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="subdate[<? echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['submissiondate'];?>">
          <input type="text" name="nextupdate[<? echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['nextupdate'];?>">
      </td>

      <td>
          <input type="submit" value="Set Date" name="setdate">
        </form>
      </td>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use foreach...

```
foreach ($_POST[nextupdate] as $rowId => $time)
    {
    // do db update
    }
```

Edit: Just realised you have more than one input per form.

Why not name each input with an array name:

```
<input type="text" name="form_data[<?= $row_id ?>][subdate]">
<input type="text" name="form_data[<?= $row_id ?>][nextupdate]">
```

In PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST[form_data] as $rowId => $values)
    {
    $subdate = $values[subdate];
    $nextupdate = $values[nextupdate];

    // do SQL stuff
    }
```